# Error :- syntax error in update statement

Tags: .net, vb.net

Please give the solution for this error.

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click


    Try

        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("update tblSales SET NoOfCars=@noofcars,Date=@dte where CarNo=@cno", con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@noofcars", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = nudnoofcars.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dte", OleDbType.Date).Value = dtpdate.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@cno", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = cmbno.Text


        Dim flag As Integer = 0
        con.Open()
        flag = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        If flag > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Record updated")
            DisplayRecord()
            ClearControl()
        Else
            MsgBox("Something went wrong.....Record is not updated")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Close()
        End If

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: The error is in the SQL not in vb.net, perhaps cmbno.Text isn't numeric, tblSales  didn't have that structure, try that update query in SSMS

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS - it's widely regarded as shouting.

Comment: I assume that MS Access is used and `Date` is a reserved word in MS Access, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/reserved-words

Comment: yes I use MS Access

Comment: but Insert and delete are working and only update is not working

Comment: See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-ae9d9ada-3255-4b12-91a9-f855bdd9c5a2 - basically you need `[Date]` instead of `Date`

Comment: why DATE keyword working in update and delete  but   not working in update

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot the **SET** keyword in your command text. Try "update tblSales **SET** NoOfCars=@noofcars,Date=@dte where CarNo=@cno"

Comment: I ADD SET BUT IT'S NOT WORKING

Comment: Are you still getting "ERROR :- SYNTAX ERROR IN UPDATE STATEMENT"?

Comment: yes still getting error